# Create mutable Digraph from an existing non-mutable subgraph_view

Tags: networkx

I do the following. But when I try to modify a node in `new_graph` I get a `TypeError: 'AtlasView' object does not support item assignment`

```py
    def get_my_nodes(source=None, distance=0):
        pre = [n for n in nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(G, source=source, depth_limit=distance)]
        post = [n for n in nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(G.reverse(), source=source, depth_limit=distance)]
        return set(pre + post)

    my_nodes = get_my_nodes(n, distance=dist)

    def filter_node(n):
        if n in my_nodes:
            return True
        return False

    subgraph_view = nx.subgraph_view(G, filter_node=filter_node)
    
    new_graph = nx.DiGraph(subgraph_view.copy())
    new_graph['my_node']['weight'] = 25  # <- this raises a TypeError: 'AtlasView' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the AtlasView, which is read only on the inner level (see the [docs...](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.classes.coreviews.AtlasView.html#networkx.classes.coreviews.AtlasView)).

The easiest solution imo is to use `nx.set_node_attributes`:

```
def get_my_nodes(source=None, distance=0):
    pre = [n for n in nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(G, source=source, depth_limit=distance)]
    post = [n for n in nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(G.reverse(), source=source, depth_limit=distance)]
    return set(pre + post)

my_nodes = get_my_nodes(n, distance=dist)

def filter_node(n):
    if n in my_nodes:
        return True
    return False

subgraph_view = nx.subgraph_view(G, filter_node=filter_node)

new_graph = nx.DiGraph(subgraph_view.copy())

#new_graph['my_node'] is an AtlasView object (read only)

nx.set_node_attributes(new_graph, {'my_node': 25}, name='weight')
```

Comment: Does this also modify the original graph `G` or only the copy `new_graph`?

Comment: It modifies only the copy; `new_graph`